# Is Cramer's V the right tool to use?

Tags: categorical-data, cramers-v

I am trying to see if there's any correlation between awareness of a program and several demographical variables (gender, religion and education)

Is Cramer's V the right tool to use since they are both categorical variables?

Also, when I import my data onto SPSS, do I have to further define my data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are treating your variables as ***nominal*** categorical † , then Cramer's V (an effect size statistic), perhaps with a chi-square test of association (a hypothesis test), will give you some information as to whether there there is an association between variables.  You should still address, though, if the degree of association is large enough to be of practical importance.

I don't know the answer to the question about SPSS.

---

† It's possible that you want to treat *education* as an ordinal categorical variable.